# Async REST response

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, amqp

I'm designing a **REST API** where some operations are propagated to **AMQP** queues. When message is processed (with error or successfully) the client must be notified. My first thoughts were to boot lightweight embedded **HTTP** server when client library is initialized, so message processing mechanism can also emit an HTTP request to the server about how went the operation execution. Any other / better ideas of how to implement this?

Comment: It is a well written article about it here http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/

Comment: ooh, I like the 303 at the end.  I'm not doing that at the moment.

Comment: OK. so with RestAPI, http (PUT, PATCH, DELETE, POST) all change state on the server and your server-side process raises the 'self.changed()' event... is your question on what protocol to use to connect various (remote) observers of the 'changed' event when it occurs on a URI resource on the server?